# Cannot find main class in bukkit plugin

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I am having trouble with my plugin. The error is "Cannot find main class 'turtdle.abilities.Main'" (I know I spelled turtle wrong, but it is my username.)

This plugin is for my server. I have already tried completing the plugin.yml file (with author, version, etc.) I also tried changing the plugin name to "Main." I have also tried moving the yml around with no success.

```
package turtdle.abilities;

import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.permissions.Permission;
import org.bukkit.plugin.PluginManager;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin{

    public Permission playerPermission1 = new Permission("turtdle.abilities.get");
    public Permission playerPermission2 = new Permission("turtdle.place.bedrock");
    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        getLogger().info("onEnable Has been enabled for abilities plugin! BOOP!");
        new PlayerListener(this);
        new BlockRestricter(this);
        PluginManager pm = getServer().getPluginManager();
        pm.addPermission(playerPermission1);
        pm.addPermission(playerPermission2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        getLogger().info("onDisable Has been triggered for abilities plugin");
    }

    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label,
            String[] args) {
        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("hello") && sender instanceof Player) {
            Player player = (Player) sender;
            player.sendMessage("Hewwooo, " + player.getName());
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }
}
```

```
package turtdle.abilities;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;

import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.PlayerDeathEvent;

public class PlayerListener implements Listener{
    public PlayerListener(Main plugin) {
        plugin.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, plugin);
    }
    @EventHandler
    public void onDeath (PlayerDeathEvent e) {
        Player player = e.getEntity();
        if (!player.hasPermission("turtdle.abilities.get")) {
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "OOF");
        }
        else {
            {
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "you should've abused...");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
package turtdle.abilities;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.block.Block;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.block.BlockPlaceEvent;

public class BlockRestricter implements Listener{
    public BlockRestricter(Main plugin) {
        plugin.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, plugin);
    }
    @EventHandler
    public void onBlockPlace (BlockPlaceEvent e) {
        Player player = e.getPlayer();
        Block block = e.getBlock();
        if (!player.hasPermission("turtdle.place.bedrock") &&  block.getType().getId() == 7) {
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You CAN'T PLACE THIS " + ChatColor.BOLD + "BLOCK! " + ChatColor.RESET  + ChatColor.RED +  " it is ILLEGAL");
            e.setCancelled(true);

        }
    }
}
```

```
plugin.yml: 
main: turtdle.abilities.Main
name: TurtdleAbilitiesCore
version: 0.2.9
author: CakeyTheTurtdle
description: ExclusiveWolfHuntplugin
commands:
   hello:
      description: When you're lonely
      usage: /hello
```

Hey here is my whole error

https://pastebin.com/FAieE0Lr

Comment: How are you exporting this plugin?

Comment: I go to file, Export, jar file (in java dropdown), then just plugin.yml, then I don't edit anything else and click finish.

Comment: Perhaps the period in the package name is affecting it somehow, making it think the package name is `turtdle` and is looking for class `abilities`

Comment: You haven't specified here. Is this a compile-time error or a runtime-error?

Comment: @Sean I tried changing the package name to just turtdle, but the error remains the same

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is not correct, unfortunately.

In the Pastebin you linked, we can see that the error is the following:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: turtdle.Main
```

When Bukkit is trying to load your main class, it is looking for the class `turtdle.Main`. The reason this is strange is your plugin.yml tells it to look for `turtdle.abilities.Main`, which it is not doing.

My guess for the cause of the issue is that sometimes when the project is being compiled, your IDE may not actually grab the edited plugin.yml file to put in the final jar. To fix this, complete the following steps:

1. Open your project folder and delete any/all of the following files/folders if they exist:

   - bin/
   - target/
   - YourPluginName.jar
2. Go to your server's folder and delete YourPluginName.jar there as well
3. Recompile your project and add the fresh jar file to your plugins folder.

Hopefully, this should resolve the issue. Your plugin.yml file and code both look fine and in theory should work. This is the only thing I can think of that would cause the issue.

Best of luck!

Comment: I tried to delete the contents of bin, and i got an error when loading eclipe

I had a backup thankfully